Florida Photography Privacy Law: Company Employee Taking Pictures of Me Without My Consent
Looking for any guidance on this issue. It was one of those "Get three free nights at a hotel, all you gotta do is attend the 2hr mandatory sales pitch! :)" demon packages. But some bs went down and the salesperson became hostile.
During a timeshare sales pitch, I asked the salesperson if it was okay to pour a drink for myself in one of the model rooms. After I asked twice for permission, they told me "you can try." (Think they believed it was all rubber or something.) I then proceeded to pour myself a drink.
As I had my back turned to pour the drink, my friend walks up and tells me they took pictures of both of us on their private phone.
I believe it was in an attempt to incriminate me and potentially have to pay for my covered stay. I ended up calling 911 which rerouted to hotel security. I complained and requested the photos be deleted, which they sent me an email on letting me they would confirm.
I have not gotten a response to the email and am pretty ticked off. Luckily no financial hardships were incurred but wtf dude. Is there any grounds for me to sue the hotel?


Is there any grounds for me to sue the hotel?

No.
You don't have a right to not have pictures of you without your consent under Florida law or federal law, when someone can view you with their own eyes.
California has stricter laws on rights of publicity, requiring that you be compensated when your image is used for commercial purposes, but there is no parallel law in Florida.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
